# On Linux, can I get 3D acceleration with a Nvidia card w/o X?

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, opengl

I like Linux.

I like OpenGL.

I don't like X.

On Linux, is there anyway to get 3D acceleration from my Nvidia card without X? Ideally, I'd have the kernel boot, get to a console, then somehow get into a "graphics mode", where my entire monitor is just a single OpenGL screen ... and I draw stuff to it with OpenGL. Without X. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: what aspect you do not like about x?

Comment: Duplicate that was not migrated :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326641/opengl-without-x-org-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

Well it should be possible to use the framebuffer with hardware acceleration, see [here](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Framebuffer#3D_hardware_acceleration).

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia's binary driver only works with X.  You can, however, run a headless X server.
See the section on "UseDisplayDevice" "none" in the README:

ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/190.36/README/appendix-b.html#UseDisplayDevice

I believe the future Gallium + nouveau stack will work sans X, but it's still under heavy development now.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a section on [Competitors to X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Competitors_to_X).

Among them, a possible match for what you want is [DirectFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectFB), but it says that "The [Direct Rendering Infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Infrastructure) [which is in X] ... may make these efforts redundant"

Unless you plan on writing your own operating system and then writing the applications on top of it, I would recommend sticking with X. It's been developed and used for decades, and I'm pretty sure there isn't any good replacement for it out there.

Answer (score -1):

From everything I can find it looks like OpenGL needs X.

- [OpenGL supported implementations](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/implementations/) include

  - X Window System for *nix
  - GLX on Linux (*OpenGL and GLX and the X server integration of GLX, are Linux system components*)
- [Mesa 3D and Direct Rendering Infrastructure](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/)

  - *The Direct Rendering Infrastructure is a framework for allowing direct access to graphics hardware under the X Window System*